# How can I define a function to calculate the moving average in a dataframe?

Tags: python

I try to calculate the moving average of one column in my data frame:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW9o1.png)

I tried this code first:

```
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]-3):
    df.loc[df.index[i+3],'SMA_4'] = np.round(((df.iloc[i,1]+ df.iloc[i+1,1] +df.iloc[i+2,1]+df.iloc[i+3,1])/4),1)
```

It worked, however, I want to define a function that can calculates the moving average and I can use different windows, then I tried this:

```
def movingaverage (values, window):
    weights = np.repeat(1.0, window)/window
    sma = np.convolve(values, weights, 'valid')
    return sma
```

But the result is an array and when I append it to the dataframe, it says the lengths are different.
So how should I write the function to use the column from my dataframe directly, and then automatically append the result to my dataframe as a new column as long as I run the function? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling

```
s = pd.Series([i for i in range(10)])
s.rolling(4).mean()

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    1.5
4    2.5
5    3.5
6    4.5
7    5.5
8    6.5
9    7.5
dtype: float64
```

You can apply custom functions if you want